# Adding a fragment to android.R.id.content enables clicks on background fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've and Android Application. I want to display a fragment in the bottom of the screen on top of everything (like a dialog, but in the bottom).
I'm adding a fragment to android.R.id.content:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
transaction.add(android.R.id.content, new MyFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

The fragment is displayed, but the views that are under the fragment are still recieving user inputs (scroll, clicks). How can I stop this behaviour like in dialogs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your root layout to clickable true so it will no more click on background fragment.

eg.

```
<LinearLayout
android:clickable="true"
>

.........
Your Other Layout
.........
</LinearLayout>
```